# Refrain Spark from replacing underscores with spaces when loading files with native methods

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am loading a lot of files in a Spark job, all of them have names of the kind: "*file_owner.extension*". The code I use to read them is:

```
 JavaPairRDD<String, PortableDataStream> imageByteRDD = jsc.binaryFiles(sourcePath);
```

but I see that underscores are replaced with a blank space. When I then try to match the name of the loaded file, of course I get an error.
I can't find anything about it in the manuals and I would prefer to let the source code untouched. Does anybody know how to stop this behaviour? I would also avoid a "`replace -space- with -underscore-`", because it is not the right way to procede either. Here is an example of the extracted files.

```
fileName extracted by the key of the PairRDD created as above: Capture11 (Custom).PNG
fileName extracted with a FileVisitor in Java 1.7: Capture11_(Custom).PNG
```